# What is a harmonic conjugate of $u=Arg(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $u=Arg(z)$ be a function maps $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ to $ (-\pi,\pi]$.

How do i find a harmonic conjugate of $u$ when $Arg(z)\in (-\pi,\pi)$?

Comment: This question was also asked and answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384853/finding-harmonic-conjugate-for-argz/2522809#2522809).

Comment: This question was also asked and answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384853/finding-harmonic-conjugate-for-argz/2522809#2522809).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\log(z) = \log|z| + i \arg(z)$